# How can I create a custom email when a user registers to my wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins, wordpress-login

In the sender name box , the emails that the user gets when they register says wordpress. I want all messages to say my company name.

when a user resets their password, it says wordpress in the sender names area...

how can I fix this

Comment: use `wp_mail_from_name` hook. eg: 
`add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', function( $name ) {
 return 'company name';
});`

Comment: where would I place this code, and would I have to delete anything or ?

Comment: placed a code in functions.php in your theme folder

Comment: So paste the code in the themes functions.php , and only place my company name where it says company name ?

Comment: yes, lets try it once

Comment: That is a correct answer! Thanks ... I wish I could vote up or give you check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `wp_mail_from_name` hook.

placed a code in functions.php in your theme folder.

eg:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', function( $name ) { 
  return 'company name'; 
});
```